# Print specified value from hash Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'd like to know how get the specified field from Hash.

```
{"codeid"=>120023, "eppocode"=>"1BOBO", "prefname"=>"Pikant", "level"=>7}
```

I have this Hash and i want to get `level` field (7) becouse i need to compare it afterwards
Thanks!

Comment: Does `h['level']` not work? (Assuming the hash is in `h`, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Standard Hash Accessors

You can use either [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) or [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) for this. There are other ways to do this too such as [pattern matching](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html), but those are overkill for what you're doing.

For example:

```rb
h = {
  "codeid"   => 120023,
  "eppocode" => "1BOBO",
  "prefname" => "Pikant",
  "level"    => 7,
}

h["level"]
#=> 7

h.dig "level"
#=> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
hash = {"codeid"=>120023, "eppocode"=>"1BOBO", "prefname"=>"Pikant", "level"=>7}
hash["level"]
#=> 7
```